# Reverse DNS / PTR with Fasthosts shared hosting enviroment

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, ptr-record, email

I'm not that clued up on all aspects of DNS so apologies if this is a stupid question of sorts. Basically I have a VPS with one provider(Xeneurope) and the domain names with another(Fasthosts). Not ideal but its what I inherited.

Anyway for the most part this hasn't been an issue, but I'm wanting to send out HTML emails to our customers. But when I started sending test emails, a lot of email providers just wouldn't accept them. AOL & Yahoo being 2 that spring to mind.

After a bit of research it seems like I need to have have reverse DNS setup for the VPS IP address before certain providers will accept emails from it.

However I'm not sure how to set this up with Fasthosts, as they say its only supported with a dedicated server from them, at present its only the domain names that I have with them. Is there anyway I can work around this with a bit of DNS jiggery pokery, since they don't allow me to add any PTR records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly you are sending these mails from Xeneurope, so fasthosts is not involved in setting the PTR. the rDNS of your xeneurope server should match its hostname (a record) and smtp helo.

see
 http://www.xeneurope.com/clients/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=23

the sender domains used in those mails do not have to match that hostname, its perfectly valid to have helo/a-record/rDNS mymailserver.example.net and send mails using sender domain bla@example.org hosted on a different server (assuming you don't have any other technologies like SPF set up which define what mailservers may send mail for that domain)

Comment: Yea, aside from providing the domain name Fasthosts aren't doing anything. So its Xeneurope that i need to contact. Thanks, i'll contact them and get this sorted hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Authority about reverse DNS is rooted with whoever "owns" the IP range. Only ways around it would require convoluted NS instead of PTR records in the reverse zone, which you will hardly be given when PTR is already denied.

The politics behind it might well be that they do not want the risk of servers sending direct email  (IP reputation issues if anyone does it wrong accidentally or maliciously!) if they only get paid VPS rates from you.

BTW, properly set up SPF records already help with mail deliverability, and these ARE under your control if you have the forward zone.

Comment: I do have access the SPF records, i'll have a look into setting them up. Cheers!